# Can QueryParams be allowed in RequestMatcher from Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am currently working on a personal project and I am setting up the backend security with Spring Security. I have an endpoint that requires a queryParam and I can't figure how to add that to the RequestMatcher.

If you know a bit of Spring Security (Like me ), this Bean will look very familiar to you. I've spent weeks to understand how this works and to actually make it work.

```
 @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/students/{studentId}").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/students").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/companies/list?sortBy=" + CompanySortBy.ALPHABETICALLY).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/v1/companies/{companyId}").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/companies/").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer -> oauth2ResourceServer
                        .jwt(jwt -> jwt
                                .decoder(jwtDecoder())))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
```

The requestMatcher that is not working properly is the

> "/api/v1/companies/list?sortBy=ALPHABETICALLY"

Controller method for this endpoint

> @GetMapping(path = {"/list"}, consumes =  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
> public ResponseEntity getAllCompanies(@RequestParam("sortBy") CompanySortBy sortBy) { // Controller logic}

I can't figure it out how to get around this and there is also not that much information about this since this is a very recent feature.

The other endpoints defined in the bean work just fine, even the one with the URI Paramter.

If I login and get a Token I can access the resources but if not this is the error I get

> org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied

I've tried to set it up with and without the Enum, use the ** to allow anything after the /list path.

If there is any documentation about this that you can find helpfull I would love to have it.

Thanks for the help,
Georges.

Comment: Why would you want to add the query parameter with a value for that matter to the matcher, which isn't supported by the way as it is a Path matcher it will only match the path not the parameters.

Comment: Just remove the query part from your `requestMatchers`. Query parameters are ignored.

Comment: `RequestMatcher` is not a recent feature, there are plenty implementations of it. If you need to provide security based on the query string, you can provide a custom implementation of `RequestMatcher` and use `http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(new MyRequestMatcher())...`. Take a look at `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry#requestMatchers(org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher...)`

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you for all of your answers, and forgive me for my "ignorance" in this matter. All of you were right and helped me to understand that the problem was not in Spring Boot, but in my API request from the fronted, the path was incorrect.  Again, thank you.